# Как сохранить в папке картинку полученную от пользователья через форму?

Tags: php

Никак не получаетсья сохранить в папке  картинку который пользователь загружает через форму.В базу данных они попадают но в папку который я указал нет .

Очень прошу помочь.

Вот **форма**

```
<form action="addnewpost.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Image">Image:</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="Image"/>
    </div>
        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Add New Post" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Директория папки**

[image: Директория папки]

и **php** код

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){

        $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["Title"]);
        $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["category"]);
        $post = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["Post"]);

        // тут время ничего интеречного
        date_default_timezone_get("Asia/Baku"); 
        $current_time = time();
        $date_time = strftime("%B-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S",$current_time);

        $admin = "Bulbasaur";

        // тут работаем с картинкой 
        $image = $_FILES["Image"]["name"];

        // переменная для загрузки в папку upload картинку полученную из формы
        $target = "upload/".basename($_FILES["Image"]["name"]);

        if(empty($title)){
            // скучная проверка
            $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Title can't be empty";
            redirect_to("addnewpost.php");
        } else if (strlen($title) < 4) {
            // еще одна скучная проверка
            $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Title should be at least 4 characters";
            redirect_to("addnewpost.php");
        } else {
            // скучная проверка базы данных все работает я проверял
            global $select;
            $Query = "INSERT INTO  `admin_panel`(`datetime`,`title`,`category`,`author`,`image`,`post`) 
            VALUES('$date_time','$title','$category','$admin','$image','$post')";

            $execute = mysqli_query($connection, $Query);

            // тут перемещаем полученный файл в папку upload
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Image"]["tmp_files"], $target);
            if($execute){
                $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"] = "Post added bruh";
                redirect_to("addnewpost.php");
            } else {
                $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Something went wrong.Try again bruh";

                redirect_to("addnewpost.php");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Image"]["tmp_name"], $target);` это `tmp_name`,а не `tmp_files`. При условии, что все остальное правильно, это ваше решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Никак не получаетсья сохранить в папке картинку который пользователь загружает через форму.В базу данных они попадают но в папку который я указал нет.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Image"]["tmp_name"], $target);
```

Это `tmp_name`,а не `tmp_files`.

При условии, что все остальное правильно, это ваше решение.

Есть возможность проверять, если перемещение произошло.

```
$moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Image"]["tmp_name"], $target); 
if($moved){
    // make your changes
}
```

[Док move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: спасибо вам большое